# Copy specific elements of an array with CUDA Thrust permutation iterator

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have an array of `glm::vec3` with `count * 3` elements. I have another array which contains `int` indices of the elements to copy. An example:

```
thrust::device_vector<glm::vec3> vals(9);
// vals contains 9 vec3, which represent 3 "items"
// vals[0], vals[1], vals[2] are the first "item", 
// vals[3], vals[4], vals[5] are the second "item"...

int idcs[] = {0, 2};
// index 0 and 2 should be copied, i.e. 
// vals[0..2] and vals[6..8]
```

I tried to use permutation iterators, but I cannot get it to work. My approach is:

```
thrust::copy(
    thrust::make_permutation_iterator(vals, idcs),
    thrust::make_permutation_iterator(vals, idcs + 2),
    target.begin()
);
```

But of course this will only copy `vals[0]` and `vals[2]` instead of `vals[0] vals[1] vals[2]` and `vals[6] vals[7] vals[8]`.

Is it possible to copy the desired values from one buffer to another with Thrust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can combine the idea of [strided ranges](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/strided_range.cu) with your [permutation iterator](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) approach to achieve what you want, I think.

The basic idea is to use your permutation iterator method to select the "groups" of items to copy, and we will select the 3 items in each group using a set of 3 strided range iterators combined into a zip iterator.  We need a zip iterator for the input, and a zip iterator for the output.  Here is a fully worked example, using `uint3` as a proxy for `glm::vec3`:

```
$ cat t484.cu
#include <vector_types.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>


#define DSIZE 18


template <typename Iterator>
class strided_range
{
    public:

    typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<Iterator>::type difference_type;

    struct stride_functor : public thrust::unary_function<difference_type,difference_type>
    {
        difference_type stride;

        stride_functor(difference_type stride)
            : stride(stride) {}

        __host__ __device__
        difference_type operator()(const difference_type& i) const
        {
            return stride * i;
        }
    };

    typedef typename thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>                   CountingIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::transform_iterator<stride_functor, CountingIterator> TransformIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::permutation_iterator<Iterator,TransformIterator>     PermutationIterator;

    // type of the strided_range iterator
    typedef PermutationIterator iterator;

    // construct strided_range for the range [first,last)
    strided_range(Iterator first, Iterator last, difference_type stride)
        : first(first), last(last), stride(stride) {}

    iterator begin(void) const
    {
        return PermutationIterator(first, TransformIterator(CountingIterator(0), stride_functor(stride)));
    }

    iterator end(void) const
    {
        return begin() + ((last - first) + (stride - 1)) / stride;
    }

    protected:
    Iterator first;
    Iterator last;
    difference_type stride;
};

typedef thrust::device_vector<uint3>::iterator Iter;

int main(){
// set up test data
  int idcs[] = {0, 2, 5};
  unsigned num_idcs = sizeof(idcs)/sizeof(int);
  thrust::host_vector<uint3> h_vals(DSIZE);
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i ++) {
    h_vals[i].x = i;
    h_vals[i].y = 100+i;
    h_vals[i].z = 1000+i;}
  thrust::device_vector<uint3> d_target(num_idcs*3);
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_idcs(idcs, idcs + num_idcs);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_idcs = h_idcs;
  thrust::device_vector<uint3> d_vals = h_vals;
// set up strided ranges for input, output
  strided_range<Iter> item_1(d_vals.begin()  , d_vals.end(), 3);
  strided_range<Iter> item_2(d_vals.begin()+1, d_vals.end(), 3);
  strided_range<Iter> item_3(d_vals.begin()+2, d_vals.end(), 3);
// set up strided ranges for output
  strided_range<Iter> out_1(d_target.begin()  , d_target.end(), 3);
  strided_range<Iter> out_2(d_target.begin()+1, d_target.end(), 3);
  strided_range<Iter> out_3(d_target.begin()+2, d_target.end(), 3);
// copy from input to output
  thrust::copy(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(item_1.begin(), item_2.begin(), item_3.begin())), d_idcs.begin()), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(item_1.begin(), item_2.begin(), item_3.begin())), d_idcs.end()), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(out_1.begin(), out_2.begin(), out_3.begin())));
// print out results
  thrust::host_vector<uint3> h_target = d_target;
  for (int i = 0; i < h_target.size(); i++)
    std::cout << "index: " << i << " x: " << h_target[i].x << " y: " << h_target[i].y << " z: " << h_target[i].z << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t484 t484.cu
$ ./t484
index: 0 x: 0 y: 100 z: 1000
index: 1 x: 1 y: 101 z: 1001
index: 2 x: 2 y: 102 z: 1002
index: 3 x: 6 y: 106 z: 1006
index: 4 x: 7 y: 107 z: 1007
index: 5 x: 8 y: 108 z: 1008
index: 6 x: 15 y: 115 z: 1015
index: 7 x: 16 y: 116 z: 1016
index: 8 x: 17 y: 117 z: 1017
$
```